# How to get article url in a given category?

Tags: twig, shopware

I'm trying to make a scroll on products in a given category for articles in shopware 6. I've managed to extend the `product-detail html.twig` file to add the next and previous on the page. The problem I'm facing is how to generate the URL links in a given category.

```html
{% sw_extends '@storefront/page/product-detail/index.html.twig' %}
{% block base_content %}
    <a href="https://xxxxx.com/xxxxx/SW1001" class="previous">&laquo; Previous</a>
    <a href="https://xxxxx.com/xxxxx/SW10015" class="next">Next &raquo;</a>
    {{parent()}}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

With the twig function `seoUrl`, you can generate links to other pages.
After the URL you can add query strings for the right pagination, see the example:

```html
{{ seoUrl('frontend.navigation.page', { navigationId: 'ID' }) }}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, i used the seoUrl function to get the link for a particular article, 
{{ seoUrl('frontend.detail.page', { productId: '1035e9ee7d27486e9f30ed88939fece1' }) }}
but am stuck on how to generate the productId of all products in a category using the seoUrl function.